# SDF Deploy error: Partial Content

Tags: netsuite, suitecloud

When I try to deploy a Suitecloud Development Framework project from Eclipse, I get the following error in the error log:

```
!MESSAGE The remote server returned an error:

https://system.netsuite.com:443/app/suiteapp/devframework/ideinstallhandler.nl - Partial Content
```

I'm doing this on a brand-new blank SDF project, so it's definitely not a problem with my code. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have [enabled SDF features in NetSuite account](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4724921034.html). In my case I had forgotten to enable SDF in the sandbox; once I turned on the feature the error went away.

To enable it, go to Setup > Company > Enable Features > SuiteCloud, and make sure the SuiteCloud Development Framework checkbox is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I added `SuiteApp Deployment` permission on the custom role under setup section and got rid of the error.